# Error in pandas "AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_title'"

Tags: pandas, histogram

I have a dataframe from which I want to plot a column named similarity into a histogram using pandas. This is the code I used in ipython:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline throws an error but why?
%matplotlib auto

Df = pd.read_csv('file1.csv')
file1_hist = Df.hist(column= 'similarity', bins =50, color= 'red')
#setting labels for title and axes throws an error, why?
file1_hist.set_title('File 1 Histogram')
file1_hist.set_xlabel('similarity(%)')
file1_hist.set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

Firstly, I am unable to enter '%matplotlib inline'. The error says `UnknownBackend: No event loop integration for u'inline'. Supported event loops are: qt, qt4, qt5, gtk, gtk2, gtk3, tk, wx, pyglet, glut, osx` Therefore, I put in '%matplotlib auto' but I'm not sure if this is right.

Also, when I try to add title/x/y axis names, I get an error that says : `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'set_title'`

Could someone help me with what is going on?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DataFrame.hist()` returns you an array of axes, because if you have multiple columns and if you will not filter them using `column` parameter `DataFrame.hist` will plot multiple subplots - one for each column. Each of those subplots will have its own axes:

```
In [266]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(5, size=(5, 3)), columns=list('abc'))

In [267]: df
Out[267]:
   a  b  c
0  4  1  0
1  4  0  0
2  4  4  1
3  1  0  4
4  2  0  1

In [268]: axes = df.hist(column='a', bins =50, color= 'red')

In [269]: axes
Out[269]: array([[<matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot object at 0x0000000012167908>]], dtype=object)

In [270]: axes.shape
Out[270]: (1, 1)

In [271]: type(axes)
Out[271]: numpy.ndarray

In [272]: type(axes[0][0])
Out[272]: matplotlib.axes._subplots.AxesSubplot
```

So try this instead of your code:

```
file1_hist[0][0].set_title('File 1 Histogram')
file1_hist[0][0].set_xlabel('similarity(%)')
file1_hist[0][0].set_ylabel('Frequency')
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. However, since I have specified the column to be 'similarity', I should not be getting subplots, should I? I also only see 1 graph as the output?

Comment: @Natasha, please check the example (demo) i have provided in my answer - i'm also plotting a histogram for a single column - `a`. But `DataFrame.hist()` returned a 2D __array__ of axes...